# Populate dropdown from database in .Net

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

My database code:

```
USE Student
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spDisplayCountry
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT countryName
    FROM CountryList
END
```

This code creates a stored procedure that I want to use from the C# code.

C# code to retrieve data:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Connection String
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeContext"].ToString();    

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDisplayCountry",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);    // Fill Dataset

    countryList.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["countryName"].ToString();
    countryList.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["countryId"].ToString(); // to retrieve specific text feild name.

    countryList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];   // assigning Datasource to DropDown List
    countryList.DataBind();  // binding dropdown list.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the **names** of the columns to display to `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` - not values of those columns - plus: you cannot assign  `CountryId` if you don't retrieve that in your stored procedure!

So it should be

```
countryList.DataTextField = "CountryName";
countryList.DataValueField = "CountryId";
```

and you need to change your stored procedure to be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDisplayCountry
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CountryId, CountryName
    FROM dbo.CountryList
END
```

Furthermore, if you only retrieve one set of data (which you normally do), there's really no point in instantiating a `DataSet` (that could hold several related sets of data) - just use a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);    // Fill DataTable
.....
countryList.DataSource = dt; 
countryList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for your suggestion.